# Loadrunner TC protocol

Tags: truclient

How to add dynatrace header in TC protocol scripts of LoadRunner? Steps to add dynatrace header in TC protocol.Is it the same way we do in web http protocol i.e, cmd prompt or different?

Answer (score 0):

There is a JS API to do these kinds of requirements. Please check the UtilsA.addAutoHeader(header, value, merge) from [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/tc/en/2020/Content/TruClient/reference/asyncronous_functions.htm). There is also a sync version of addAutoHeader, but the latest TruClient suggest to use the async version.